# unable to start sensu-client service getting rubygems.rb not loaded error

Tags: sensu

I am trying to start sensu-client but getting below error

:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in`'

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 1):

:4:in `require’: cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in`'

Issue resolved after providing execute permissions for /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby

drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Jun  6 17:55 ruby